# Defining a map in Groovy using a variable

Tags: java, groovy

Why when I use

```
['type':x, z:y]
```

Where

```
x = 'Car'
z = 'Speed'
y = '1000'
```

I get a map equal to

```
[type=Car, z=1000]
```

and not

```
[type=Car, Speed=1000]
```

and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surround the `z` with `()`

```
['type':x, (z):y]
```

As per [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps).

Answer (score 0):

If the keys of your Map are always strings, the following approach should also work

```
['type':x, "$z":y]
```